# Is it possible to exist non-isomorphic (k,l) Ramsey graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Definition : A (k,l) Ramsey graph is a graph on r(k,l)-1 vertices that contains neither a clique of k-vertices nor a independent set of l-vertices.

My question : Is it possible to exist non-isomorphic (k,l) Ramsey graph?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have non-isomorphic Ramsey graphs. For a census of known Ramsey graphs see [this](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/ramsey.html) on McKay's web page.